# Prestashop Language.php appears prevents access to shop and admin

Tags: php, prestashop

I'm at a complete loss to resolve these issues and desperately need help.

I was about to start upgrading my prestahsop 1.4.4 to 1.5 in a new (folder) location. I installed the new prestashop without any problems. It is in a different folder to my existing prestashop.

But quite since that installation I cannot access my existing prestashop, either admin or store. I had no problems whatsover with it until then.

These are the error reports:

STORE FRONT

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /hermes/bosweb25a/b56/nf.logorythm/public_html/logostore/classes/Language.php on line 554

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /hermes/bosweb25a/b56/nf.logorythm/public_html/logostore/classes/Language.php:554) in/hermes/bosweb25a/b56/nf.logorythm/public_html/logostore/classes/Cookie.php on line 300

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /hermes/bosweb25a/b56/nf.logorythm/public_html/logostore/classes/Language.php:554) in/hermes/bosweb25a/b56/nf.logorythm/public_html/logostore/classes/Cookie.php on line 300

Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in /hermes/bosweb25a/b56/nf.logorythm/public_html/logostore/classes/FrontController.php on line 228
```

ADMIN

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /hermes/bosweb25a/b56/nf.logorythm/public_html/logostore/classes/Language.php on line 554

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /hermes/bosweb25a/b56/nf.logorythm/public_html/logostore/classes/Language.php:554) in/hermes/bosweb25a/b56/nf.logorythm/public_html/logostore/admin0811/header.inc.php on line 29

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /hermes/bosweb25a/b56/nf.logorythm/public_html/logostore/classes/Language.php:554) in/hermes/bosweb25a/b56/nf.logorythm/public_html/logostore/admin0811/header.inc.php on line 30

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /hermes/bosweb25a/b56/nf.logorythm/public_html/logostore/classes/Language.php:554) in/hermes/bosweb25a/b56/nf.logorythm/public_html/logostore/admin0811/header.inc.php on line 31

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /hermes/bosweb25a/b56/nf.logorythm/public_html/logostore/classes/Language.php:554) in/hermes/bosweb25a/b56/nf.logorythm/public_html/logostore/admin0811/header.inc.php on line 32

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /hermes/bosweb25a/b56/nf.logorythm/public_html/logostore/classes/Language.php:554) in/hermes/bosweb25a/b56/nf.logorythm/public_html/logostore/classes/Cookie.php on line 300

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /hermes/bosweb25a/b56/nf.logorythm/public_html/logostore/classes/Language.php:554) in/hermes/bosweb25a/b56/nf.logorythm/public_html/logostore/classes/Cookie.php on line 300

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /hermes/bosweb25a/b56/nf.logorythm/public_html/logostore/classes/Language.php:554) in/hermes/bosweb25a/b56/nf.logorythm/public_html/logostore/classes/Cookie.php on line 300

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /hermes/bosweb25a/b56/nf.logorythm/public_html/logostore/classes/Language.php:554) in /hermes/bosweb25a/b56/nf.logorythm/public_html/logostore/classes/Tools.phpon line 104[/quote]
```

The code at Language.php l554 is

```
 foreach ($result AS $row)
```

This is under `/** Load all languages in memory for caching`

The code at FrontController.php l228 is

```
if ($cart->{Configuration::get('PS_TAX_ADDRESS_TYPE')})
```

The code at Tools.php l104 is

```
header('Location: '.$url);
```

This is under `/** redirect to another admin page`

The code at Cookie.php l300 is

```
return setcookie($this->_name, $content, $time, $this->_path, $this->_domain, 0, true);
```

I hope this information is enough for someone to point me in the right direction. I need urgent assistance.

Many thanks,

K

Comment: Are the two installs sharing a database?

Answer (score 0):

There may be several reasons to these issues. Can you please reply to the following questions:

1) While installing Prestashop 1.5 have you created a new database for it, or you used the same database as of the old prestashop 1.4 ?

2) Are your Prestashop 1.5 installed site is running fine?

3) Have you read  http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Updating+PrestaShop and http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS14/Updating+PrestaShop ?

Kindly enable errors at your site, and then it will be possible to see the exact issue.

Thank you